# Using build flavours to start multiple instances of an Android Service

Tags: android, gradle, android-service, android-productflavors

### Problem

I have an application with two modules in it, one `SDK` module that runs a background service, and one `UI` module that contains the application UI.

This application has two build flavours to have slightly altered user interfaces - the `SDK` module is unchanged. These two flavours have a different application ID, so they can both be installed simultaneously on the same device.

The problem I am encountering is that the service that is started by the `SDK` module can only have one instance - apparently even when run from different build variants. Therefore when I try and run both variants at the same time, the second one does not start the service - only `onStartCommand` is called.

### Previous Attempts

I have attempted to create two classes which both inherit the main service and placed each one in the two flavour folders, making the actual service class name different. This did not seem to have an effect.
I have also tried various methods of starting the service itself - `startService` or `bindService` - neither had an effect.

### Question

How can I allow two build flavours to run separate instances of the same service simultaneously - is this even possible?

Comment: Could you post also the manifest definition for your service?

Answer (score 0):

Android service can have only one instance. System does not allow creating multiple instances of the same service.

Having said that, there are two things you can do as a workaround:

1) Create two slightly different entries for two services in Manifest.xml. You would also need to provide onCreate() and onStartCommand() functions but most of the service code can be common and shared. onCreate() and onStartCommand would have the bare minimum implementation and would call the common shared code.

2) Another option is to use IntentService. IntentService only runs as long as there are pending tasks but it allows creating multiple instances. You can use this option if it fits your application design.